# How to Show Nested Attribute for Corresponding User?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I only show the `:accept`checkmark for the `dueler` who is the `current_user`?

Right now there is a `check_mark` for each dueler, which means a user who is not the dueler can accept on behalf of the other user.

```
Dueler.last
 id: 20,
 user_id: 78,
 challenge_id: 178,
 duel_id: 13,
 accept: nil>
```

**duels/show.html.erb**

```
<% @duel.duelers.each do |dueler| %>
    <% if current_user.id == dueler.user_id %>
        <%= form_for @duel do |f| %>
          <%= f.fields_for :duelers do |accept_fields| %> # Only Want to Show One Checkmark for current_user.id == dueler.user_id 
            Accept?  : <%= accept_fields.check_box :accept %>
          <% end %>
          <%= f.submit %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to retrieve just the dueler for the current_user (with an SQL query)

in the action

```
@duel = Dueler.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
```

in the view

```
<%= form_for @duel do |f| %>
  Accept?  : <%= f.check_box :accept %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, but now I ran into a new problem if you want to help me over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753687/routing-error-uninitialized-constant-for-nonexistent-controller :)