# Routing Error: uninitialized constant for nonexistent controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

Upon checking `submit` I get `Routing Error: uninitialized constant DuelersController`

**`duels/show.html.erb`**

```
The loser(s) will <%= @duel.consequence %><br><br>
If everyone succeeds they will <%= @duel.reward %>
<%= form_for @dueler do |f| %>
  Accept? <%= f.check_box :accept %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

There is no `DuelersController` only **`DuelsController`**

```
def show
  @dueler = Dueler.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
  respond_with(@duel)
end

def set_duel
  @duel = Duel.find(params[:id])
end
```

Once a `user` clicks `submit` how can I redirect the user back to the show page?

```
Dueler.last
 id: 20,
 user_id: 78,
 challenge_id: 178,
 duel_id: 13,
 accept: nil> # For example redirect back to duels/13 with accept: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I was distracted. I think your problem is actually another, you have to explicitly specify the controller and action here.
On a side note, maybe you'll have to change the way you fetch your parameters on the set_duel action (I don't remember if rails sets the id automatically), anyway:

```
#Assuming you want to call set_duel upon submission
<%= form_for @dueler, :url => { :controller => "duel", :action => "set_duel" }, :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
  Accept? <%= f.check_box :accept %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have a `dueler` and `duel` model. `duel` `has_many :duelers`. Is there a way to just have it where when a user updates dueler it `redirects_to` duel show page?

Comment: That gives same error as question :/ To clarify I'm trying to do this without creating a "DuelersController". Thanks for trying!

Comment: Sorry to waste your time @AnthonyGalli.com, I updated the answer, please take a look and let me know.

Comment: No worries buddy :) It gives error: `No route matches {:action=>"set_duel", :controller=>"duel", :id=>"13"}`. I thought maybe the action should be `show`, but same error `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"duel", :id=>"13"}`

Comment: I also tried this way, but I get a different error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778376/how-to-update-dueler-in-duels-controller?noredirect=1#comment64928351_38778376. Been at this for awhile :/

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com, can you update the post with your routes.rb?
It should contain a route to allow the usage of set_duel.